# Win 10 localhost NodeJS v14 Mongoose 3.8.16 cannot connect to MongoDB 4.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot use NodeJS + Mongoose (3.8.16) to connect to MongoDB (4.4) on Win 10 localhost.

Here is the simple `test.js` code:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');

mongoose.connection
    .once('open', (e) => console.log(e))
    .on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog' });

dog.findSimilarTypes(function (err, dogs) {
    console.log(dogs); // woof
});

dog.save(function(e){console.log(e)});
```

Here is part of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "simplevote",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.*",
    "cookie": "*",
    "jade": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "MD5": "*",
    "node-uuid": "*",
    "async": "*",
    "marked": "*",
    "nodemailer": "*",
    "nodemailer-direct-transport": "*"
  }
}
```

## Here is the problem

I run in command prompt like this: `node test.js`

Up to `mongoose.connection`, there is no `console.log` code printed.  Completely NOTHING.

The connection status is `connecting`, and it hangs in there like something is running...

- Both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` did not work
- bindIP is set to `0.0.0.0`
- `mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/myapp');` did not work

Can you all please tell me how to fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Mongoose 3.8.16 is not compatible with MongoDB 4.4](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html).

Comment: Thanks @str, So I can only go back to elder version of MongoDB?

Comment: Or maybe you should upgrade your **six years old** version of Mongoose instead?

Comment: @str I totally agreed.  But our client give us a set of this garbage and all JS code inside are based on these 6 years old version of Mongoose/Mongo

Comment: @str And I can't even start step 1: connect to a DB.  It just hanged there!